# How to get content of file in sharepoint using sharepoint rest api

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, file, java

I am using below endpoint to get the content of file in sharepoint:

```
https://<site>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('folder name')/Files('file name')/$value?binaryStringResponseBody=true
```

But this is returning a response in octet stream and the content type of response is application/octet-stream. Is there a way to get the content in human readable format directly? If not , is there a way to convert it into other format in java?

Comment: As far as I know, neither the REST API or the Client Object Model supports the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

We need to use the below API:

GET `https://mysite.sharepoint.com/<site_name>/_api/web/lists(guid'<list-id>')/items(<item-id>)/File`

api of sharepoint using list id and item id obtained from /getchanges api. Then use the ServerRelativeUrl field of response to obtain file contents by calling :-

GET `http://mysite.sharepoint.com/<site_name>/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('<url>)/$value?binaryStringResponseBody=true`

Reference URL:

[How to point to/get the file contents or file from SharePoint changes api call](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/186348/how-to-point-to-get-the-file-contents-or-file-from-sharepoint-changes-api-call)

**how to get file content from sharepoint list using restapi in java**

Similar question discussed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422868/how-to-get-file-content-from-sharepoint-list-using-restapi-in-java

Comment: Thanks for answering this. But as i mentioned in the question getFileByServerRelativeUrl api is returning the response in octet-stream. Iam looking for an api to get response as plain text.

Comment: You have to change the header type that you are accepting. Put it to accept json. Like this:
`headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
                        'odata-version': ''
                    }`